# Trying to send a string message from javascript server to client using sockets; when pressing HTML button

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sockets, server

I am new to this area so forgive me if I fail to explain my question well.

I am essentially trying to send a string *"Hello, I connected to the port"* to my Javascript client, only when I have pressed a HTML button.

FOR TESTING PURPOSES:

I have been successful in running a client and server Javascript socket connection, and can receive data back and forth. However when trying to link this to my html page I fail to connect them and send data.

CLIENT.JS:

```
const net = require('net');

const client = net.createConnection({ port: 9898 }, () => {
  console.log('CLIENT: I connected');
  client.write('CLIENT: Hello this is client!');
});

client.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
  client.end();
});

client.on('end', () => {
  console.log('CLIENT: I disconnected from the server.');
});
```

SERVER.JS

```
const net = require('net');

const server = net.createServer((socket) => {
 socket.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
 });
 
 socket.write('SERVER: Hello! \n');
 socket.end('SERVER: Closing connection now \n');
}).on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});

server.listen(9898, () => {
 console.log('opened server on', server.address().port);
});
```

if you save the above code and run them using the lines:

```
node server.js
node client.js
```

You will find that they send messages between them quite nicely.

***The issue starts when I try to run my html page (which is served using node.JS on port 8083)***
(I server my HTML page using *npx http-server --cors*)

An approach I tried was to place the code in client.js into a function and then call it in my html button:

```
<input type = "button" onclick = "outputData()" value = "Display">
```

(outputData being the function that contains the code in client server)

***I'm not sure if its even something that can be done, but I'd like to essentially start my server.js from my HTML page, when a button is clicked, so that it can begin sending the data. I'd want to run "node client.js" on terminal and see that messages are coming through as server.js would have been started from my webpage***

Any advice would be highly appreciated. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: use socket.io https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/index.html and use the emit function inside your outputData() function that's it/

Comment: socket.emit('data', myData);

Comment: @EddwinPaz Hi, thank you for your help. Will I still be able to receive messages onto my client.js?

Comment: send and receive. so yes.

Comment: @EddwinPaz Unfortunately nothing is still happenening. I made sure to connect my html to my client.js using "src=..." but I think its failing to host that onto the required port. Simply running "node client.js" runs it on port 9898 but to actually run it from my html page fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using Websockets. Where my webserver acted as the client, and I adjusted my server.js to the following:

SERVER.JS

```
const WebSocket = require("ws");

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 9898 });

wss.on("connection", ws => {
    console.log("New client connected!");
    
    ws.on("message", data => {
       console.log(`Client has sent us: ${data}`);
       
       ws.send(data.toUpperCase());
    });
    
    ws.on("close", () => {
       console.log("Client has disconnected!");
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/dcode.css">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
      <title>WebSockets</title>
   </head>
   
   <body>
      
      <script>
        const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9898");
        
        ws.addEventListener("open", () => {
           console.log("We are connected!");
           
           ws.send("Hey, how's it going?");
        });
        
        ws.addEventListener("message", ({ data }) => {
           console.log(data);
        });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Information about socket.io library, https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/index.html

Sending message index.html

```
        <html>
   <body>
      <input type="button" onclick="javascript:sendMessage()" value="Click here"/> 
      <script>
         const sendMessage = () => {
             var new_message = {message: "this is my message"}
             socket.emit('new_message', new_message);
         }
         
      </script>
      <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
      <script>
         const socket = io("http://localhost:8080");
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

server.js

```
socket.on('new_message', (data) => {
    var New_Details = {  
        message: data.message  
    }; 

    socket.broadcast.emit('update_message', New_Details);
    console.log(data.username + ' just wrote ' + data.message);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your annswer. I will try and implement it. For your js file did you place that code within a function block "function javascript:sendMessage() { <code>}

Comment: I implemented this and my server.js is listening at the port however it seems as if I am not sending out the message correctly. I wonder if it because the html isn't connecting to the js file. I used the line <script type = "text/javascript" src = "client.js"></script>

Comment: check your network on your browser you can see websocket connection there.

Comment: see if your .js files are actually loading and executing properlly.

Comment: They don't show up. Could it be related to using localhost:8080? I know that I can't host the socket on the same port that my webserver is ran (8083) so I tried to use 9898 however that didn't change the outcome. It also doesn't let me use 8080 from my server.js to listen in as the address is already in use

Comment: check your server.js and see what port you are using and make sure it;s only for the socket. then use the same port on the client side.

Comment: I made sure to adjust them both to use port 9898 but still no luck. My server.JS code remains unchanged, but I have replaced my client.js with your example for testing purposes. On the index.html, I have switched the port number to match e.g. const socket = io("http://localhost:9898). I'm not sure what I'm missing

Comment: try to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Comment: Still no luck. The code above... are they two separate solutions as I've been trying them together?

Comment: I tried running just the code you have to get a simple test but when running "node server.js" I get back an error "ReferenceError: socket is not defined". Which install should I run in order to define socket?

Comment: the errors I'm getting in the console include 1)GET http://127.0.0.1:8083/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) and                        2)(index):13 Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
    at (index):13